# Как оформить переход от множественного числа к единственному (обобщение)?

Tags: единственное-множественное-число

> Впереди нас ждёт много чудесного, сегодня же перед глазами пройдут
>   **несколько удивительных по силе и красоте мозаик, но такой вы больше
>   никогда и нигде не увидите. Она прекрасна именно в своём поиске**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если требуется именно обобщение, я бы сделала такой переход:

«…перед глазами пройдут несколько удивительных по силе и красоте мозаик, но такой, какая была создана в XII веке, вы никогда и нигде не увидите. Фреска этого времени прекрасна…"

Comment: Лена, я не случайно оформляю подвопросье цитатой. То, что Вы предлагаете, означает переписывание авторского текста на свой лад, а у меня - КНИГА! ЛОшку вручаю, но не уверена, что автор примет правку: там сплошные даты, буквально на каждом шагу! Поставьте мне пятёрку за вопрос: напряжёнка с нумерологией, в репе (репутации) не должно быть чётных! У мя!